# Is it possible to normalize each individual kernel input to a Conv2D in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Using `tf.keras` I have a `Conv2D` layer with a kernel size of say `5x5`. Is it possible to have each `5x5` patch be normalized by the L1 norm (or potentially any other transformation on that patch) before it is being fed into the `Conv2D` layer ?

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by making a custom layer:

```py
class L1NormalizationLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(L1NormalizationLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # No trainable weights for this layer
        super(L1NormalizationLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Calculate L1 norm along the last axis (assuming channels_last data format)
        l1_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(inputs), axis=-1, keepdims=True)

        # Normalize each patch by dividing by the L1 norm
        normalized_inputs = inputs / l1_norm

        return normalized_inputs

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

Comment: thank you very much. as i'm very new to keras, could you elaborate on how to use that new layer in conjunction with the Conv2D layer ?

Comment: i'm new to keras, but i don't think this is doing what i need. your suggested code seems to simply normalize the ENTIRE input, but what I need is rather to normalize each individual 5x5 input patch before it gets multiplied by the conv-kernel. this is different from normalizing the input as a whole

Comment: basically, referring to this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d
i want to be able to modify that VIRTUAL tensor mentioned in point 2 before the convolution operation.